# How to get bot to only trigger on one message per user given specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've got a bot that once a user messages within a channel it triggers my work. The problem I'm running into is that users don't understand that each message they send, triggers another instance of my bot to work. Is there a way to either allow the user to only send 1 message? or maybe collect a series of messages after the initial message for a period of time? My implementation below:

```
bot.on("message", (async msg => {

    await initialConversation(msg, triggerChannel);

}));

function initialConversation(message) {
    message.author.send("Getting the right people for you!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit too broad since a larger number of solutions could be employed to help resolve your issue. In any of those cases however, there is one thing you may want to do, which is to disable the input field in the UI to prevent any subsequent messages to be entered until the desired response is returned from the initial request.

Besides the UI change, you could have some state variable that checks for messages coming from a particular user and throwing an error in cases where one is already in progress.

Comment: Makes sense. just remove the option from the user. Thanks